# Increment item by 1 in cakephp 4

Tags: php, cakephp

Hey guys I want to add a simple button which will +1 the stamp count column via a simple click of a button. i am not sure what to add for the controller, would really appreciate the help

[image]

Comment: Seems like a straight-forward "stamp" function that takes the user ID as a parameter?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.